# Getting user of C# aspx project and finding the current user.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to check if the current user of a web app matches a particular one by doing this:

```
             string t = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

when i console log this string i receive: UserOne

The problem i am running into is this:

```
   if(t.Equals("UserOne"))
   {   
      //this part does not fire off
   }
   else
   {
      //this part fires off
   }
```

i don't understand. I'm clearly receiving the value of system.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; and as far as I can tell the if statement logic is correct.

Please help.

Comment: use `Trim` before `Equals` just to rule out any possible spaces around your user name

Comment: tried this and unfortunately still did not work.

Comment: there must be some difference; you can probably post your screenshot of debugging value of `t` at `if`

Comment: im copying the value of string t directly to ensure that they're identical, so i don't think thats it. Any other idea's?

Comment: I don't have any idea but one thing I can tell is that it is **a very bad idea to compare user name like that** to adjust what a user can see or do. This is bad because you are using hard-coded string and also because you should typically use roles for that purpose so that you can control which user can do what without updating source code.

Comment: The hard coding was simply to make it easier to explain my problem. I am actually getting a list of usernames from web.config that will have read only access to the site

Comment: Before if (..) , try to  Debug.Assert (t=="UserOne" ,"Something wrong").  if the condition is false, outputs the  specified message and displays a message box that shows the call stack.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running this in a console app, `WindowsIdentity.Name` will return your user name.

If you are running this in a ASPX site, `WindowsIdentity.Name` may return something completely different, e.g. the user name associated with the app pool in which your ASPX application is running.

For more information on this, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645601/windowsidentity-and-classic-net-app-pool).